# Boy lives in a cave with aliens and later goes to war with them

Tags: story-identification, aliens, novel

I read a book where a boy befriends these nice aliens and lives in a cave with them while another alien invasion wages on earth. In any case, he eventually comes out of the cave, and yells or thinks "great googli moogli" and then goes blind the next day. He goes to help his friends fight the war and is joined by the nice aliens who also fight.

The evil aliens ride the bike like contraptions and CANNOT get off of them for long, or else they'll go crazy.

One of the nice aliens (he's hard on the outside and soft on the inside when you get to know him) ends up dying to protect the boy who came out of the cave. This book is part of a series.

Comment: This sounds like a hilarious book, especially the bit about yelling *great googli moogli*.

Comment: Great Googly Moogly is the catchphrase of the Beast from [Maggie and the Ferocious Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggie_and_the_Ferocious_Beast).

Comment: Then he might have said "Great God almighty"but I'm almost positive it was the former. And yes, the book was hilarious. I loved it

Comment: Also, while it was later coined (for younger audiences)by the Beast from Maggie and the Beast  (a show which I love)the phrase "Great Googly Moogly" was the original"catchphrase" of musician/singer Frank Zappa. He was mentioned in the book. But thanks for the insight, Daniel Roseman.